# MVC Code First: Why does no relationship exists between webpages_Membership and UserProfile tables?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, simplemembership

I am using the SimpleMembership providers in MVC with a code first design.
I see that EF created 5 tables: UserProfile, webpages_Membership, webpages_OAuthMembership, webpages_UsersinRoles and webpages_Roles.

UserProfile has a PK of UserID and so does webpages_Membership. webpages_OAuthMembership has an FX of UserId. Yet there is no actual relationship between these tables. IN other words no actual indexes were created. I understand that EF will automatically create these relationships if you include the navigational property in the models. My problem is, how do I know what the name of the classes are for webpages_Membership and webpages_OAuthMembership so I can include them as strongly typed navigational properties in my UserProfile class?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider the webpages_* tables as being completely separate from your UserProfile table.

The SimpleMembership provider makes allowance for the identity to be provided separate from the core application, so that you are able to allow users to use their Google or Microsoft accounts instead of requiring them to create yet another account just for your site.

The most immediate example of this from a user perspective is Stackoverflow, where you can use Google, Facebook and so forth to login.

If the built in identity provider was tightly coupled with the UserProfile, then this would be harder to accomplish.